# Checkout Field Editor plugin filter hook to set custom display rules for checkout fields

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have just purchased the plugin Checkout Field Editor for WooCommerce from Theme High.
I need to create a custom display rule condition for fields.
They provide the filters hook:

```
apply_filters( 'thwcfe_show_field', $show, $field_name );
```

I have tried the following code, but it does not work.
Can someone help?

```
function display( $field_name='test' ) { 
    $show =true; 
    return $show; 
}
add_filter('thwcfe_show_field', 'display');
```

The true / false options works but I can't make it specific to the `$field_name = 'test'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using this filter in a correct way… First there are **2 arguments** for the hooked function *(one is missing)*.

To restrict the filter to a specific field name, you need an **`IF`** statement and between `$field_name` and the value to be tested, you need to use `==` or `===` [comparison operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), but not **`=`**.

So your code is going to be:

```
add_filter('thwcfe_show_field', 'display_test_field', 10, 2 );
function display_test_field( $show, $field_name ) { 
    if ( 'test' === $field_name ) {
        $show = true;
    }
    return $show; 
}
```

where **`10`** is the hook priority and **`2`** the number of arguments for this hook.

It should better work now.

[Documented WordPress `add_filter()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/)